# How to catch the trigger error messages in lightning recordeditform

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to display the error message of trigger in lightning UI.Tried in following way but default error message i am getting.

[image: this message i am getting.]

I want to show the message which i have added in trigger.

Please find the below code.

### Component:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 
<aura:registerEvent name="evt_dataTableUpdate" type="c:evt_dataTableUpdate"/>

<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="popuplib"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">
    <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordViewForm" 
                          recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
                          objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}"
                          fields= "{!v.fieldsArray}"
                          columns="{!v.numberOfColumns}"
                          mode ="{!v.mode}"
                          onsuccess = "{!c.showToast}"
                          oncancel="{!c.closeModal}" 

    <lightning:messages />
    </lightning:recordForm> 
</aura:if>
```

### Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var str = cmp.get('v.fieldsToDisplay').replace(/\s+/g,'');
        var array = str.split(",");
        cmp.set('v.fieldsArray', array)    
    },

    showToast : function (cmp, event, helper){
       var appEvent = $A.get('e.c:evt_dataTableUpdate');
        appEvent.setParams({
            "refreshMe" : "we dont need a param.. must lookup if it's practice to use one"    
        });
        appEvent.fire();    
            cmp.find('notifLib').showToast({
            variant: 'success',
            message: "The account has been updated."

        });
        cmp.set("v.isOpen", false);
        cmp.find("popuplib").notifyClose();
    },
   closeModal: function(cmp, event, helper) {
       // set "isOpen" attribute to false for hide/close model box 
       cmp.set("v.isOpen", false);
       cmp.find("popuplib").notifyClose();
    },

})
```

### Trigger:

```
trigger DuplicateEmail on Contact (before insert, before update) 
{
try{
    Set<String> setEmailID = new set<String>();
    Set<Id> setContID = new set<ID>();
    for (Contact Contact : System.Trigger.new) 
    {
        if ((Contact.Email != null) &&  (System.Trigger.isInsert ||  (Contact.Email != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(Contact.Id).Email))) 
        {
            setEmailID.add(Contact.Email);
            setContID.add(Contact.id);
        }
    }

    List<Contact> lstCOntact = [select id ,email from contact where email in :setEmailID and id not in :setContID ];
    Map<String, Contact> contactMap = new Map<String, Contact>();

    for(Contact cont : lstCOntact)
    {
        contactMap.put(cont.email, cont);
    }   

    for (Contact Contact : System.Trigger.new) 
    {
        if ((Contact.Email != null) &&  (System.Trigger.isInsert ||  (Contact.Email != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(Contact.Id).Email))) 
        {
            if(contactMap.containsKey(Contact.Email))
            {
                Contact.Email.addError('A Contact with this email address already exists.');
            }
        }   
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
}   
}
```

Comment: Can you try putting < lightning:messages /> outside the aura:if?

Comment: Tried but no use.....error is undefined.

Comment: Any suggestions for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute named **oncancel** on `lightning:recordForm.` Refer [Record Form
 specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/specification) to know all the available attributes for lightning:recordForm.

Please remove that attribute from your component markup and try again.

> Note:- Error message from Triggers are supported with Lightning Data
>   Service.

Comment: actually oncancel is a valid attribute, its just not listed in the documentation